# How do I disable automatic creation of ".AspNet.Consent" cookie?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

ASP.NET Core 2.1

I think this gets set automatically. How do I prevent that?

Comment: See [GDPR support in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr).

Comment: @MarkG Yes I think the cookie was a leftover from the template, it isn't being set once I deleted all that stuff. Maybe add that as an answer and I'll close it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just came across the same issue. My 100% cookie-free website had a cookie, created by `ASP.NET Core`.
As @mark-g pointed out in his comment, it is mainly added to support GDPR: Let users of your web page opt-in/out for the allowance to collect and keep data about them.

In all usual cases I'd recommend to go this route as designed by Microsoft. Keep the ASP.NET cookie and make use of the `_CookieConsentPartial.cshtml` for all personal data you might want to keep about the users.

In my special case, I have a very simple web page. No data is collected, also not from any third parties. I dont need the cookie consent and the ASP.NET cookie. In this case, can remove this cookie just by commenting out one line:

In Startup.cs comment out the line:

```
// app.UseCookiePolicy(); No cookies used at all!
```

Then clear all caches and remove the cookie, reload the page and it is gone.